# React Typescript: get sessionStorage after reload of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

After the User Sign In, a authentication token is saved in the `sessionStorage` and the Page gets Reloaded. Now after the reload I want to read that data and store it in a `state` but the render dont change from `<Login />` to `<Layout>...`

```
export default class Home extends React.Component<any, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            auth: true,
        }

        this._auth();
    }

   public render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.auth ?
                    <Login /> :
                    <Layout>
                    ...
                    </Layout>
           </>
        )
   };

   private _auth(): void {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("accessGranted") !== "")
            this.setState({ auth: true });
        else
            this.setState({ auth: false });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do not call `setState()` in `constructor()`. Instead, if a component
> needs to use a local state, assign the initial state to `this.state`
> directly in the constructor.
>
> `componentDidMount()` invokes immediately after a component mounts.
> You can call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidMount()` and
> triggers an extra rendering, but this happens before the browser
> updates the screen, calling `render()` twice.

[read more here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-setstate-react-components/)

Either you can return the value of your `sessionStorage` from `_auth` method and use that value to create the state inside the constructor, OR you can simply call this._auth inside `componentDidMount()` which is still okay but mainly used for async computations, side effects etc.

Comment: The function ```_auth``` is now returning a boolean value and its called inside the render, but its async and the ```<Login />``` Component is still loaded.

Comment: `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` calls are synchronous. And please, if you updated your _auth method, also update the question.